# pv and pvc - kube- efs

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-efs

I am using PV with EFS. I have created a PV and PVC. My PV goes back to released status after I delete my StatefulSets. When I delete and re-apply my StatefulSets, it does not get attached to the same PV, instead the PVC status shows pending. My question is how do I get my pods in StatefulSet rebound to the same PV?

```
[kubeXpress]# k get pv

NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   **STATUS**     CLAIM            STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE

efsvol    1Mi        RWO            Retain           **Released**   default/efsvol   aws-efs                  10m

[kubeXpress]# k get pvc
efsvol    **Pending**                                       aws-efs        10m

[kubeXpress]# k get po
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0                                       0/1       **Pending**   0          4m

[kubeXpress]# k describe po web-0
Events:
Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  2m (x37 over 12m)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 6 times)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to create a new PVC for a new Pod to use an existing PV.

If you delete `PV.Spec.ClaimRef` reference in PV settings, any new PVC with appropriate setup could use it. Or if you want to assign PV to the exact PVC, you can fill `PV.Spec.ClaimRef` with the name of PVC and then create PVC with that name.

Don't forget to use `Retain` policy for a PV to prevent deletion after it is released.

Example of PV:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain            #Here is policy
  claimRef:                                        #Here is claim reference
    name: claim1
    namespace: default
```

Example of PVC:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
metadata:
  name: "claim1"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "1Gi"
  volumeName: "pv0001"
```

Comment: Can you also show me the yaml for the PVC?

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer

Comment: This answer is incompatible with Kubernetes manual: "Once bound, PersistentVolumeClaim binds are exclusive, regardless of how they were bound. A PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping."